# ansible: pass variable to a handler

Tags: ansible

I use an "eye" as a supervisor and on changes in templates have to runs something like this:

```
eye load service.rb
eye restart service.rb
```

I want to define this as a single handler for all the apps and call it like

```
eye reload appname
```

And in a handler operate like this:

```
- name: reload eye service
command: eye load /path/{{ service }}.rb && eye restart {{ service }}
```

But I can't find a way to pass variable to a handler. Is it possible?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694249/ansible-using-with-items-with-notify-handler

Comment: @valeriy-solovyov, it doesn't make any difference except the ```&&``` would work as expected. Parametrised handlers just work in ansible 2.0 so the propper way is to use service name in the handler name:

```- name: reload eye {{ service }}
      shell: eye load /path/{{ service }}.rb && eye restart {{ service }}```

Comment: This is supported as of 2.1.1.0. Make sure you're using quotes around any line which has variable interpolation.

Comment: @hryamzik Is this the "eye" you're referencing? https://github.com/kostya/eye

Comment: yes https://github.com/gitinsky/ansible-role-eye

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this. I understand your desire to use Ansible as a programming tool, where 'handler' is a 'function' you 'call', but it's not.

You can invent a dozen of tricks to do what you want, but result would be a total mess, hard to read and even harder to debug.

The key issue is that ansible does not support 'argument passing' to anything (except for modules). All tricks you read about or invent by yourself will change global variable. If you ever wrote at least bit in any language , you know, that program where every function is using global variables (for read and write, and to pass arguments) is fundamentally flawed.

So, how to do this in a very good and readable Ansible?

Yes, just wrote a separate handler for each service. It's the cleanest and simplest Ansible. Easy to read, easy to change.

BTW: if you have to actions in a chain, do not join them with '&&'.

Use two separate handlers:

```
- foo:
  notify:
    - eye reload
    - eye restart foo
```

(note, that order of handlers is defined in the handlers list, not the 'notify' list).

Btw, if you have few services you will save on multiple reload operations - 'eye reload' would be called once.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative: Just don't use handler but register variables

I found [another solution](https://gist.github.com/alces/ab0c72ca425cc73829b9) that suggest simply not using handler but tasks.

You will need an extra step initializing the list of services to restart and yet another step to append the services to the list but you are much more flexible when to do things.

Note the `unique` at the final step, which is simulating the restarting of the services, preventing duplicate calls.

```yaml
---
- name: Restart Services if config changed
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Set empty list of services to restart
      set_fact:
        ServicesToRestart: []

    - name: Create some config for 'my_service'
      template: src=my_config.j2 dest=/tmp/my_config
      register: my_config

    - name: Add service 'my_service' to restart list if config was changed
      set_fact:
         ServicesToRestart: "{{ ServicesToRestart + ['my_service'] }}"
      when: my_config.changed

    - name: Create some config for 'other_service'
      template: src=my_config.j2 dest=/tmp/my_config2
      register: my_config

    - name: Add service 'other_service' to restart list if config was changed
      set_fact:
         ServicesToRestart: "{{ ServicesToRestart + ['other_service'] }}"
      when: my_config.changed

    - name: Create some other config for 'other_service'
      template: src=my_config.j2 dest=/tmp/my_config3
      register: my_config

    - name: Add service 'other_service' to restart list if config was changed
      set_fact:
         ServicesToRestart: "{{ ServicesToRestart + ['other_service'] }}"
      when: my_config.changed

    - name: RestartServices
      debug:
        msg: "Restarting {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ServicesToRestart | unique }}"
      when: ServicesToRestart
```

Answer (score 0):

handlers/main.yml:

```
- name: restart my service
  shell: eye load /path/{{ service }}.rb && eye restart {{ service }}
```

So you can setup variable through default
defaults/main.yml:

```
service : "service"
```

or you can define {{ service }} though command line:

```
ansible-playbook -i xxx path/to/playbook -e "service=service"
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html

PS: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-

```
example
---
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum: name=httpd state=latest
  - name: write the apache config file
    template: src=/srv/httpd.j2 dest=/etc/httpd.conf
    notify:
    - restart apache
  - name: ensure apache is running (and enable it at boot)
    service: name=httpd state=started enabled=yes
  handlers:
    - name: restart apache
      service: name=httpd state=restarted
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

If you ever want to flush all the handler commands immediately though, in 1.2 and later, you can:

```
tasks:
   - shell: some tasks go here
   - meta: flush_handlers
   - shell: some other tasks
```

Comment: That'll work, but only for a single application that needs to be restarted. A handler will only be fired once at the end of the playbook. It would work though if the handler loops over a list and for each service that needs to be restarted an item is added to that list via `set_fact`.

Comment: I added example when you flush handlers before  next task. PS: Maybe you need reorganize your playbook?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this but you can use set_fact in order set facts that can be accessed by the handler.