# Is ist somehow possible to create a template of an ansible handler?

Tags: ansible

I am facing the problem that I need to define a set of similar handlers in `ansible` that differ only in a name.

Let me give an example. Here are some **tasks**:

```yaml
# tasks/main.yml
- name: Install config of OpenVPN instance 1
  notify: restart openvpn-1
  ...
- name: Install config of OpenVPN instance 2
  notify: restart openvpn-2
  ...
# Multiple more of that pattern.
```

You might think that each instance has a slightly different configuration that can be handled here.

All right. Bow the **handlers**:

```yaml
# handlers/main.yml
- name: restart openvpn-1
  systemd:
    name: openvpn-server@instance1
    state: restarted
- name: restart openvpn-2
  systemd:
    name: openvpn-server@instance2
    state: restarted
# ...
```

You see this is quite some duplicated code (not good).

I was thinking of doing something like:

```yaml
# Handler template or so
- name: restart-openvpn-{{ item }}
  systemd:
    name: openvpn-server@instance{{ item }}
    state: restarted
  loop:
    - "1"
    - "2"
    # ...
```

This is not working, I tried it.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694249/ansible-using-with-items-with-notify-handler) but this works here not so ideal as it assumes the task to be running in a `loop`. Instead I have a set of individual tasks that trigger single instances of the handlers. Also this is already in a role.

So the short question is: How can I create a handler template to avoid code redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.

E.g. I took two services and tell 'em to restart using your approach:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: restart-{{ item }}
      systemd:
        name: "{{ item }}.service"
        state: restarted
      loop:
        - "whoopsie"
        - "wpa_supplicant"
```

O/P is:

```
PLAY RECAP **********
localhost                  : ok=2
```

The main difference from your code: add quotes.

As per [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) on Using Variables:

> YAML syntax requires that if you start a value with `{{ foo }}` you quote the whole line, since it wants to be sure you aren’t trying to start a YAML dictionary. This is covered on the [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-syntax) documentation.
>
> This won’t work:
>
> ```
> - hosts: app_servers
>   vars:
>       app_path: {{ base_path }}/22
> ```
>
> Do it like this and you’ll be fine:
>
> ```
> - hosts: app_servers
>   vars:
>        app_path: "{{ base_path }}/22"
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is *not* what I am looking for. I know this can be used within the tasks. I am looking for a way to realize it in the handlers. So I want to generate a set of handlers derived from an a-priori known set of instances.